# Plasma Condensation

Tags: plasma-physics

How can a plasma with ion temperature in the order of ~10^5 K be cooled to form a solid? Is there such thing as “plasma deposition,” where you could deposit arelatively  hot dense plasma on a colder surface?

Comment: Plasma particles recombine on a a solid surface, it can be called "plasma deposition" on solid. However, some of recombining particles won't stay there; if it is hydrogen plasma against a carbon surface then those hydrogen atoms would form molecules inside the material and exit the surface because hydrogen molecules would not be chemically bound to carbon surface. But a lithium surface would trap hydrogen. So a lot depends on the plasma and surface chemical composition.

Comment: Practically speaking, would the plasma cause the solid to melt or possibly even vaporize?

Comment: Depends on plasma temperature and density, if the energy contents of the plasma is not large then it won't melt/ablate the solid surface.

Comment: If I have an ion temperature of 20-50eV and a density of 10^20 ions cm^-3. How would this work out?

Answer (score 0):

Well Plasma does not always turn into solid. It also depends on how cold the solid is. Instead what happens is that plasma turns into gas as oppositely charged particles combine. Then the gas could turn into solid by deposition. The actual plasma can not really do that as it does not have enough time.

[Can plasma turn back into gas, solid, or liquid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83538/can-plasma-turn-back-into-gas-solid-or-liquid)

However it can happen if there is enough time.